# Lost my Aliases after installing Oh my Zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I had several Aliases defined on my terminal Zsh (Mac OSx), after installing **Oh My Zsh** I cannot execute my old aliases, and by running the **alias** I see a list of many new aliases added by Oh My Zsh. Does this mean it overrode my old ones? Is it possible to recover the old aliases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you installed it in a extremely unconventional way, the aliases that were in `~/.zshrc` are now in `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`. You can copy them from there.